# What is the name of the process for a running gnome terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

1. What is the name of the process for a running gnome terminal?
2. Does each tab in a gnome terminal have a process, or all the tabs in
   a gnome terminal have the same process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `bash`. Each running terminal does have a separate process.

Comment: each tab has a separate process?

Comment: I am not too sure whether or not the tabs have. I would have carried this out, but unfortunately, I have uninstalled my default terminal. Here is what to do. Open a terminal window. Go into system monitor and look for the bash process, it should be one. Add a terminal tab and take a look at the system monitor, did it change or stayed the same?

Comment: why did you uninstall it? what are you using now?

Comment: Terminator, because I use Ubuntu GNOME (official distro) and I could not get a transparent background since this functionality has been removed due to some performance reason. I mapped Terminator to use the default configs of terminal so its partly normal. I can have multiple terms in the same window. Vertical and horizontal. [see here - dont get jealous](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xCT1P.png)

Comment: Wrong answer.  You can have any number of bash processes running that don't have anything to do with a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

it's called `gnome-terminal`. Each terminal it's an instance, then have it own process. But the tab's of one terminal are linked. If you kill the process ( `sudo killall gnome-terminal` ) all the tab's will be closed.

Comment: hummm... i don't know!

Comment: No it's not.  All I get is "gnome-terminal-server" and that's only one process -- not the several terminal window processes I have running.  Indeed, if I do a search for the mysterious program name for "Terminal" in the same way I do for "Files" it comes up with "gnome-terminal" which, as I just pointed out, is wrong.  It isn't the name of the process in the `ps` command.